# WCF Service Issue

Tags: wcf

I am facing issue of the WCF Services on staging server. The same service is running perfectly in my local pc. But when i configured the same on staging server it is giving issue saying that:

> The communication object,
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel,
>   cannot be used for communication,
>   because it is in Faulted state.

Is it related to security or anything else?

How can i fix the issue?

Regards,
Om

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might have some security issue. See how you have implemented the security. If you are using the default, the windows authentication credentials are used. For doing this, you need both the client and server use the same windows user account. Otherwise, you can use impersonation or if you don't have an issue, use no authentication to test.

The channel comes into fault if no fault contract is defined or there is some un-handled exception on the server side. Look at the possible exceptions and try loggin the exceptions on the server side.

Comment: Are you still waiting for an answer?

Comment: My concern is that i have deployed 15 services same folder, but issue is with only one. Others are working fine.

Comment: Could you find the fault or exception being generated in this case? If the channel is in faulted state, it is sure that there is some exception condition. You may check the events in the system using Event Viewer from the control panel under admin tools. Alternatively, you can check for any exception logs on the server side.